# Could not launch Mac OS X 10.7 application archived with RestKit

Tags: objective-c, macos, restkit

I'm a newbie for RestKit and developing Mac OS X application.

I'm trying to develop Mac OS X application using the RestKit.
I can run the app on debug mode of Xcode.

But I could not run the app on production mode (It means archived application).
Launch the app, this error will be occurred.

> > TestRestKit cannot be opened because of a problem.
> >      Check with the developer to make sure TestRestKit works with version of Mac OS X.
> >     You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install any available updates for the application and Mac OS X.
> >
> > Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

And I checked the system log, then I find these logs.

> > May 14 12:41:01 black-umbrella [0x0-0x26b26b].jp.co.test.TestRestKit[30585]: dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/RestKit.framework/Versions/A/RestKit
> >     May 14 12:41:01 black-umbrella [0x0-0x26b26b].jp.co.test.TestRestKit[30585]:   Referenced from: /Users/tfmagician/Desktop/TestRestKit.app/Contents/MacOS/TestRestKit
> >     May 14 12:41:01 black-umbrella [0x0-0x26b26b].jp.co.fuller.TestRestKit[30585]:   Reason: image not found
> >     May 14 12:41:02 black-umbrella com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[235] ([0x0-0x26b26b].jp.co.fuller.TestRestKit[30585]): Job appears to have crashed: Trace/BPT trap: 5

So I noticed the warning when the app is archiving.

> > Check dependencies
> >       Warning: Installation Directory starts with @executable_path but Skip Install is disabled.

I was followed this documentation to install RestKit.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x

Xcode version is 4.3.2, and I'm using master branch of RestKit.

Please help me and I would be glad if I can get any idea about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the target's `Build Phases`

[image: Project settings]

Click `Add Build Phase` (bottom right), `Add Copy Files` and add this:

[image]